# SVD of a positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ complex matrix, positive definite: $x^* A x>0$ for any $x$. 
Is it true that eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to singular values of $A$?

If $A$ is Hermitian, then it will be true from $\sigma_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i(A^*A)}$. But without assuming that $A$ is Hermitian, is it still true?

Comment: A positive definite complex matrix is hermitian in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positive definite matrices are unitarily diagonalisable and possess positive eigenvalues. Hence $A$ has the eigendecomposition $UDU^\ast$ for some unitary matrix $U$ and positive diagonal matrix $D$. Since this by itself is a [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), the eigenvalues and singular values of $A$ coincide.